# Using a loop to create multiple dataframes in R based on columns criteria

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe with 3 columns. I would like to create separate sub-dataframes for each of the **unique combinations of a few columns**.

For example, suppose we have just 3 columns,

```
a <- c(1,5,2,3,4,5,3,2,1,3)
b <- c("a","a","f","d","f","c","a","r","a","c")
c <- c(.2,.6,.4,.545,.98,.312,.112,.4,.9,.5)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I would like to get a separate dataframe for each of the unique combinations of Column 'a' and 'b'

I started with using `unique` to get a list of the unique combinations as the following,

```
factors <- unique(df[,c('a','b')])
   a b
1  1 a
2  5 a
3  2 f
4  3 d
5  4 f
6  5 c
7  3 a
8  2 r
10 3 c
```

But I am not sure what to do next.

The code below are for illustration purposes. Ideally this will be done through a loop where it uses each of the rows in `factors` to create the dataframes.

```
df_1_a <- df %>% filter(a==1, b=='a')
  a b   c
1 1 a 0.2
2 1 a 0.9

df_3_a <- %>% filter(a==3, b=='a')
  a b     c
1 3 a 0.112

.
.
.
```

Comment: you can use `split`, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942670/split-dataframe-using-two-columns-of-data-and-apply-common-transformation-on-lis)

Comment: `split(df, df[c("a","b")], drop=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda dirty and I'm not sure that answer your question but try this :

```
a <- c(1,5,2,3,4,5,3,2,1,3)
b <- c("a","a","f","d","f","c","a","r","a","c")
c <- c(.2,.6,.4,.545,.98,.312,.112,.4,.9,.5)
d <- paste0(a,b)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
df_splited <- split(df,df$d)
```

You obtain a list composed of dataframes with unique combinaison of `a`,`b`

Answer (score 0):

You can use split after you get the unique combinations you are after.

```
 a <- c(1,5,2,3,4,5,3,2,1,3)
    b <- c("a","a","f","d","f","c","a","r","a","c")
    c <- c(.2,.6,.4,.545,.98,.312,.112,.4,.9,.5)
    df <- data.frame(a,b,c,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    fx <- unique(df[,c('a','b')])
    fx_list <- split(fx,rownames(fx))
```

Comment: If you dig into the code you will find that the split.default function already does this for you. It uses the `interaction` function to handle multiple columns, and the drop parameter used by r2evans is needed (to my surprise) because the call to interaction sets drop=FALSE and you need to override it to get just the unique combinations.

Comment: Interesting I never knew that, thanks for the information!