# Remove trailing NA by group in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na, zoo

I have a data.frame with a grouping variable, and some NAs in the value column.

```
df = data.frame(group=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3), value1=1:9, value2=c(NA,4,9,6,2,NA,NA,1,NA))
```

I can use `zoo::na.trim` to remove NA at the end of a column: this will remove the last line of the data.frame:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df %>% na.trim(sides="right")
```

Now I want to remove the trailing NAs by group; how can I achieve this using dplyr?

Expected output for *value2* column: `c(NA, 4,9,6,2,1)`

Comment: Can you also have NAs in `value1` that could cause the row to be removed or is it explicitly for `value2`?

Comment: in my use case there are NA in one numeric column only... but yes in theory could be more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *lapply*, loop through group:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$group), na.trim, sides = "right"))

#     group value1 value2
# 1.1     1      1     NA
# 1.2     1      2      4
# 2.3     2      3      9
# 2.4     2      4      6
# 2.5     2      5      2
# 3       3      8      1
```

Or using *by*, as mentioned by [@Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851712):

```
do.call("rbind", by(df, df$group, na.trim, sides = "right"))
```

Comment: or in a pipe indeed: `df %>% split(.$group) %>% lapply(na.trim, sides="right") %>% do.call('rbind', .)`

Comment: @agenis ouch, not the best use of pipes. Pretty sure there is a prettier `purrr` solution to this.

Comment: Yes... one question, if I have not 1 grouping variable but more, I would need to create a custom split variable right?

Comment: Also, save some characters with good'ol `by` instead of `lapply(split(`

Comment: @agenis no, we just create list, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943166/680068)

Comment: @Henrik Thanks, I always forget "by", more comfortable with "*apply".

Answer (score 7):

You could write a little helper function that checks for trailing `NA`s of a vector and then use `group_by` and `filter`.

```
f <- function(x) { rev(cumsum(!is.na(rev(x)))) != 0 }

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(f(value2))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
  group value1 value2
  <dbl>  <int>  <dbl>
1     1      1     NA
2     1      2      4
3     2      3      9
4     2      4      6
5     2      5      2
6     3      8      1
```

---

**edit**

If we need to remove both leading and trailing zero we need to extend that function a bit.

```
f1 <- function(x) { cumsum(!is.na(x)) != 0 & rev(cumsum(!is.na(rev(x)))) != 0 }
```

Given `df1`

```
df1 = data.frame(group=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3), value1=1:9, value2=c(NA,4,9,NA,2,NA,NA,1,NA))
df1
#  group value1 value2
#1     1      1     NA
#2     1      2      4
#3     2      3      9
#4     2      4     NA
#5     2      5      2
#6     2      6     NA
#7     2      7     NA
#8     3      8      1
#9     3      9     NA
```

We get this result

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(f1(value2))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
  group value1 value2
  <dbl>  <int>  <dbl>
1     1      2      4
2     2      3      9
3     2      4     NA
4     2      5      2
5     3      8      1
```

Comment: thanks, would it work if I want also to remove leading NAs?

Comment: No. Would you want to remove both leading _and_ trailing zeros?